# Convert String List to Number in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am saving table ids as foreign key into another table using Oracle Apex Shuttle field `like(3:4:5)`. Now I want to use these IDS in sql query using `IN` Clause. I have replaced `:` with `,` using `replace` function but it shows

> no data found

message.

The following query works fine when I use static values.

```
select * from table where day_id IN(3,4,5)
```

But when I try to use

```
select * from table where id IN(Select id from table2)
```

it shows no data found.

Comment: are you sure you have 3, 4, 5 in table2 ?

Comment: im confused. the column you used on the first query is `day_id` then at the second query, you're using `id`.if its just a typo make sure the data you are expecting are in table2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what i understand you have a list like `1:2:3:4` that you want to use in a `IN` clause; you can transform the list into separated values like this:

```
select regexp_substr('1:2:3:4','[^:]+', 1, level) as list from dual
connect by regexp_substr('1:2:3:4', '[^:]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

This will return:

```
List
1
2
3
4
```

Then you can simply add it to your query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE day_id IN
    (SELECT regexp_substr('1:2:3:4','[^:]+', 1, level) AS list
    FROM dual
        CONNECT BY regexp_substr('1:2:3:4', '[^:]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
    );
```

Comment: My list showing hierarchical not same like you told above.

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you try below statement. It has working as you expected.

create table table1 (id number, name varchar2(20));
alter table table1 add constraints pri_cons primary key(id);
create table table2 (id number, name varchar2(20));
alter table table2 add constraints ref_cons FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES table1 (id);
begin
insert into table1 values (1,'Bala');
insert into table1 values (2,'Sathish');
insert into table1 values (3,'Subbu');
insert into table2 values (1,'Nalini');
insert into table2 values (2,'Sangeetha');
insert into table2 values (3,'Rubini');
end;
/
select * from table1 where id IN (Select id from table2);
```